# Python - Select min values in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like this:

[image]

How can I make a new data frame that contains only the minimum 'Time' values for a user on the same date?

So I want to have a data frame with the same structure, but only one 'Time' for a 'Date' for a user.

So it should be like this:

[image]

Comment: which one should that be?

Comment: Please format DataFrame as ascii tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort values by time column and check for duplicates in Date+User_name.  However to make sure 09:00 is lower than 10:00 we can convert the strings to time first.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'User_name':['user1','user1','user1', 'user2'],
    'Date':['8/29/2016','8/29/2016', '8/31/2016', '8/31/2016'],
    'Time':['9:07:41','9:07:42','9:07:43', '9:31:35']
}

# Recreate sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

#### Alternative 1 (quicker):

```
#100 loops, best of 3: 1.73 ms per loop

# Create a mask 
m = (df.reindex(pd.to_datetime(df['Time']).sort_values().index)
     .duplicated(['Date','User_name']))

# Apply inverted mask
df = df.loc[~m]
```

---

#### Alternative 2 (more readable):

One easier way would be too remake the df['Time'] column to datetime and group it by date and User_name and get the idxmin(). This will be our mask. (Credit to jezrael)

```
# 100 loops, best of 3: 4.34 ms per loop

# Create a mask
m = pd.to_datetime(df['Time']).groupby([df['Date'],df['User_name']]).idxmin()

df = df.loc[m]
```

---

#### Output:

```
        Date     Time User_name
0  8/29/2016  9:07:41     user1
2  8/31/2016  9:07:43     user1
3  8/31/2016  9:31:35     user2
```

Comment: @jezrael with the small dataset I had (very small) the reindex was quicker though

Answer (score 2):

**Update 1**

```py
#User included into grouping
```

Not the best way but simple

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.datetime64('2016')+
             np.random.randint(0,3*24,
                    size=(7,1)).astype('<m8[h]'),
             columns =['DT']).join(pd.Series(list('abcdefg'),name='str_val')
                ).join(pd.Series(list('UAUAUAU'),name='User'))
df['Date'] = df.DT.dt.date
df['Time'] = df.DT.dt.time
df.drop(columns = ['DT'],inplace=True)
print (df)
```

Output:

```py
  str_val User        Date      Time
0       a    U  2016-01-01  04:00:00
1       b    A  2016-01-01  10:00:00
2       c    U  2016-01-01  20:00:00
3       d    A  2016-01-01  22:00:00
4       e    U  2016-01-02  04:00:00
5       f    A  2016-01-02  23:00:00
6       g    U  2016-01-02  09:00:00
```

Code to get values

```py
print (df.sort_values(['Date','User','Time']).groupby(['Date','User']).first())
```

Output:

```py
Date       User                  
2016-01-01 A          b  10:00:00
           U          a  04:00:00
2016-01-02 A          f  23:00:00
           U          e  04:00:00
```